# Does a volatile variable in a synchronized block prevent lock elision?

Tags: java, multithreading

For example,

```
public class Counter {
    private volatile long count;

    public long vaule() {
         //Since count is volatile and this is read only,
         // We don't need to use synchronized here 
        return count;
    }

    // This method will only be accessed from a single thread.
    public void increment() {
        synchronized (this) {
            count++;
        }
    }

}
```

Suppose that the above *increment* will be only accessed from one single thread, then will the synchronized in that method be optimized out by the JIT compiler due to the Lock Elimination(Elision) optimization introduced for synchronized?

Comment: Maybe you would catch more fish if you changed the title.  Your question has nothing to do with implementing a ReadWriteLock.  It seems like your real question is something like, "Does using a `volatile` variable in a synchronized block prevent lock elision?"